# Reading text file which has forward-given line terminator

Tags: java, split, bufferedreader, filereader

In Java, I'm being given the text file location and line terminator, and I am supposed to read it line by line. 
Is there any way to override `readLine()` function, so that it reads lines from text file like `readLineModified(char lineTerminator)`.

i.e. If there is a file with content `"Foo foo $ bar bar $ foobar jonathan"` it should be separated into lines  `"Foo foo"`, `"bar bar"`,`"foobar jonathan"`?

 Code should not be using any "exotic" modules.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter-java.util.regex.Pattern-

Answer (score 4):

You can use  java.util.Scanner like so:

```
   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
   scanner.useDelimiter("$");
   while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(scanner.next());
   }
   scanner.close();
```